# Method used for breaking the loop deemed unsuitable

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, simulation

I've been working on simulating the open loop amplification of a series pass voltage regulator that I'm building as part of an assignment.

I've employed the following method for breaking the loop of the feedback circuit:

[image]

I deem it to be a good approach. It takes into account the need for the circuit to have a well defined operating point. And the approach of sticking a test signal in the non-inverting input of the diff pair resembles what I've seen being done in block diagrams in order to determine loop gain.

This is how the open loop gain looks like:
[image]

**However, the feedback I received on this in class was unexpectedly harsh.**

According to the person in charge, I should have cut the loop completely and paralleled the two resistors R3 and R4 at the non-inverting input of the diff pair, while adding an AC source at the positive terminal of the differential amplifier.

I tried to implement the suggested open loop circuit but I can't get it to work:

[image]

The resulting open loop amplification is a bit weird and slightly different from what I got with other methods.

[image]

**Why are the values of the open loop amplification different, how should I change the second simulations so that it works?**

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by " The feedback goes to the non-inverting input and it should go back to the inverting input"? As I understand it the feedback network is formed between the output of the common collector and the inverting input of the diff amp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the setup as shown with the 2nd figure works correctly. It is a rather uncommon approch because the test signal is not injected into the opening point. My doubt: The node between R3 and R4 is not AC-loaded at all (if compared with the closed loop where the base of Q4 is connected to this point).

Here is my approach: When you open the loop for finding the loop gain there are two important requirenments:

- The DC operating point must be kept. This requirement can be fullfilled using the L-C combination which you have shown in the first figure.
- Furthermore, the loading conditions at the opening must not be disturbed. That means: The node between R3 and R4 must still be loaded with the input resistance (base) of Q4.
- For this purpose, you can create a mirror of Q4 (and the associated circuitry) at this point. For simulation purposes you could copy the relevant parts of the circuit.
  But if you have a good and sufficiently correct knowledge about this input resistance, you can of, course, insert a simple resistor of this value (if it is constant over the frequency range of interest).
- As the most accurate method, one can also apply Middlebrooks "double-injection technique". This works for simulation only (not for measurements). To eliminate the loading problems at the opening, the simulation is divided into two parts: (a) injection of a test voltage and (b) injection of a test current. Then, both results are combined using a suitable formula.

Comment: So that means I am not accounting for the base resistance of the transistor Q4 when opening the loop? Also when you say "create a mirror of Q4" do you mean that I should connect to the node between R3 and R4 a complete copy of Q4 and biasing circuitry ?

Comment: I tried doing something like this: https://imgur.com/a/nBWH5D5 Probably not the right way.

Comment: @Virgil_T.  Yes, when opening the loop between R3 and R4 you disconnect the load which consists of the Q4 input resistance. This load is effective under closed-loop conditions and must be simulated when the loop is open. And yes, the most correct way is to connect a complete copy of the circuitry with Q4 at the opening.

Comment: So a complete, correct model of the open loop gain would mean: at the base of Q4 to add the two parallel resistors of the feedback network and a test voltage ac source, while at the other point (where I break the loop) to add the equivalent value of the input resistance of Q4?

Comment: No - a mirror of the two parallel resistors at the base of Q4 (where you inject the test signal) is NOT necessary - it will not have any influence on the loop gain (it is just a parallel path to the loop). By the way: The method of (a) using the L-C combination for opening the loop as shown by you and (b) building a complete mirror of the existing load at the opening is a well established method and described in several papers.

Comment: Difference being that method a) doesn't account for input impedance of Q4 and method b) does?

Comment: I did not speak about two (different) methods - the described method consists of two essential parts: (a) open the loop (ac wise only) and inject a test signal and (b) re-establish the disconnected load.

Comment: Only now I have analyzed the test setup as shown in the link (your second comment). It is not correct - what is the purposeof C2 and L2 ?  Rememeber: If the loop is closed, the base of Q4 has a DC connection to the two resistors. Hence, the mirror circuit must also directly conncted to the the voltage divider R3-R4.

Comment: So direct connection between the copy circuit and the voltage divider. Would the copy circuit still contain the common collector at the end of the circuit, or should I keep only the differential amplifier and its bias circuitry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149696/discussion-between-virgil-tibbs-and-lvw).

Answer (score 0):

Measuring loop gain by breaking the loop *and using a different port* seems... peculiar, to say the least.

Mind, such a method might garner upvotes when it's well enough written and *not manifestly wrong*, but upvotes are an extraordinarily poor method of checking technical validity.

---

A note about this site generally;

> According to the person in charge,

There is no such thing; at least not on a day-to-day question-answering basis.  This site is entirely volunteer free advice, people acting wholly independently (or, at least as far as I'm aware).

Admins or corporate accounts could speak with authority (in the sense of being authoritative within the platform), but don't answer questions on a day-to-day basis.  Moderators generally only act with authority on matters of site management or meta (acting on flagged questions, answers or comments; closing, editing or migrating posts to appropriate locations; removing offending content; etc.), as a rule preferring not to act on technical matters with that authority.  (So, no need to act sheepishly around answers given by mods, or give them any more weight than any other answer, on that basis alone that is.)

Consequently, that advice is worth what you've paid for it.

So, it would be wise not to take anything too seriously here.

This site is *most definitely not a substitute* for an accredited university curriculum; so, if you for some reason need to be trained in the exact formalism used by academia... you'd be best off asking academia.  Sign up for the relevant courses, or do the whole degree, whatever.  (Or maybe you even did, and didn't understand it; or long since forgot it, and have returned to electronics much later, as sometimes happens.  Either way, needing a refresher.  In that case, asking more specifically about those aims and goals would be suggested.)

You are -- as is always the case -- on your own, whether some advice happens to be applicable to, and correct for, whatever given situation.  Perhaps some answers provide better reasoned explanations than others; or provide actual citations; it's your duty to check all of those, and recursively in turn, and judge them as you see fit.

I would love that a disclaimer like this be posted as a heading atop... probably all of Stack Exchange, really, but as that would probably harm their revenues, it's not going to happen.  So, I'm left copying this disclaimer myself.

And perhaps this even reflects poorly on me, taking this site too seriously; I don't see anyone else setting expectations, giving disclaimers, like this.  Perhaps the manifest lack of such disclaimers is as implicating as the disclaimer itself... Or it would be, to a person of sufficient critical insight.  But therein lies the trap; sites like this, are... they're like bait for the uncritical reader, in a sense, I suppose.  Therefore my most useful urging, above all others, is to learn critical thinking, and how to research topics yourself.  I would like that to be a positive outcome of such a disclaimer as this.

Also, some may argue, this [digression] isn't answering the question, within some (any given reader's) preferred margin of directness; it's undoubtedly answering the question, but by how many degrees, is a different matter.  Which might be all the more reason not to post this disclaimer often, because how can I promote good knowledge without also getting upvotes?  Ah, but now you see the contradiction of an upvote system on technical matters.

Also, that comments like this, might technically belong better on the Meta Stack.  But no one reads Meta.  It's as if by design, . . .

Well, so it is.

---

Anyway, for my part, on this particular matter:

I don't have much use or care for the formalism of opening the loop, and what the precise best ways are to do it, or to measure it or whatever.  So, mind that I don't have a strong opinion about this, and clearly you are getting grossly similar results for either method.  I will explain, later, what I mean by "similar".

It's been a long time since I was in an academic setting, and anyway I gather you aren't doing homework either, so perhaps the exact method doesn't matter so much anyway.

I will say the first method is more likely to be correct, for several reasons:

1. A closed point in the loop has been opened into two ports.
2. The two ports can be terminated in whatever manner is most suitable/representative.
3. The two ports can be measured for impedance.
4. Most generally, 2 and 3 can be combined to say: we can measure the two-port matrix at this point.  That is, to measure the input impedance, transfer ratio, feedback (reverse transfer) ratio, and output impedance, of both ports. (Or equivalent formulations thereof.)

This is clearly not true of the bottom circuit, which connects to an entirely new port.  We know from symmetry of the particular circuit that it's not likely to be too far off, but the point of this method is to use it on any arbitrary system, not having to make adjustments for particular kinds, but treating the circuit as a black box, an unknown -- and this assumption is violated here.

If we're strictly measuring voltage gain, then the top circuit is exact (or nearly so), because we aren't interested in the input impedance (by definition, voltage gain is voltage over voltage, regardless of input or output currents), and the output impedance is essentially the output sense resistor divider, i.e. we're not too concerned about what happens at the `OUT`put proper versus the impedance on either port, or from loading of the divider.  (That said, we might still be interested in modeling the input impedance, which will be dominated by \$r_\pi\$ and \$C_{BE}\$, and attaching such a load to the divider would give a more accurate measure of loop gain in practice.  Alternately, we characterize those port impedances, and adjust for it later, on closing the loop: there is a gain term due to those two impedances acting as a divider.)

Equally valid is the method whereby voltage is injected, and the feedback is subtracted by measurement.  Subtractions of nearly-identical voltages are nontrivial in practice, but we can still simulate such a method within numerical accuracy of the simulator.  In one of your previous questions, the left circuit:

[image]

performs this directly, as the perturbation source VG2 is in series between the two ports, thus the divider is automatically loaded by the base input impedance.

Well, I say subtraction, but what's happened is the circuit has done the subtraction itself.  In general, `VF2` will be a very small signal (say, some ~mV), while `VF1` is modest (say, under a volt, to avoid shifting bias too much*).  It's very hard to measure `VF2`, particularly at low frequencies where loop gain is high.

*Notice T7 operates with hardly a volt V<sub>CE</sub>, so we would expect the linearity assumption to be violated in practice, if we actually tried to run a volt or two, AC peak.  A couple volts higher supply, or some 100s mV signal level, would be more appropriate here.  We're fine in the simulator, as it uses a linearization assumption; excitation voltage is irrelevant in SPICE.

Which conversely, is the advantage of the broken-loop method: using attenuators, we can construct a `VF2` arbitrarily small (limited by thermal noise floor, which we can average out, say using a lock-in amplifier if we really want to), and not have to measure it at all.  Mind -- give or take assumptions about impedance, of course (since our signal generator, or attenuator, won't have zero source impedance, and so gets a gain factor due to division with \$r_\pi\$ and \$C_{BE}\$; we need to check that this gain factor is known, or close enough to 1 to ignore).

So, that's a run-down of the procedure, or concept.

**My Practice**

In some sense I've both transcended, and ignored, the value or use of this procedure.  I'll explain both.

**First,** the circuit must be of suitable design.  *This is a given,* going into testing: the gain and bandwidth are *design parameters*, and I don't need to do anything more than verify they are within the expected range; precise measurements aren't important or useful, and they will vary widely with operating point and manufacture, anyway.

To my eye, the only important parts here, are that you've measured >60dB gain, and somewhere around 100kHz bandwidth (or a couple 10s MHz useful GBW, which is its own concern actually, but that's not directly important to this question).

Loop gain is in turn driven by requirements like PSRR or output impedance, or voltage ripple due to a given load step change or current ripple.  If the regulator's open-loop output impedance is say a kohm, we need to reduce it by say a ballpark 1000x or 60dB to get to 1 ohm, and maybe we want 1 ohm because we have a 100mV requirement and a 100mA worst-case step load.

Those are very hand-waved figures of course, in particular that the dB reduction in output impedance does not equal the gain.  Indeed it could go the opposite direction -- it depends on how the gain is connected, and we could just as well have a current-feedback amplifier which indeed raises the output impedance instead.  More exactly, the output impedance here is about 1/gm, and overall gm is about T2(gm) * T7(hFE).  Actually, I suppose it's worse than that, because that would be around 20S, and you have... a bit less than 1 overall, I think it was?  Well, exact figures require better than hand-waved analysis, anyway.

**Second,** overall dynamics and open-loop parameters are related.  The exact relation isn't trivial (we have the \$\frac{G}{1 + GH}\$ transfer function, which mixes the poles and zeroes of \$G\$ and \$H\$ into something new and -- given the numerical instability of polynomial roots -- in general different from either function), but I'm only looking for some specific region of interest anyway (e.g., maximum response rate with well-damped stability), and I can arrive at that by testing overall system behavior (e.g. load step response) without having to open the loop and set up a whole *thing* to measure it.  (I also don't have a DSA handy to do the measurement, anyway!)

Real systems are also messier than control-theory diagrams express.  It would be tempting to consider opening the traditional SMPS isolated error amplifier circuit at the 'X' location:

[image] 
<sup>Source: own work; modified from [UC3843_Isolation.png](https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/UC3843_Isolation.png) (disclaimer: own site)</sup>

But this would be erroneous, or at least missing something, because it's easy to view the TL431 as an error amp with input and output, but in fact the supply connection, through the opto itself, supplies a zero to the transfer function.  (The observation is: due to Miller effect, both terminals of the TL431 act as a virtual ground, at high frequencies; though that, too, is complicated by the TL431's own gain roll-off at HF.  All the more reason to model the whole damn thing, rather than trying to make it a self-contained control loop.)  The correct place to open the loop is at the `+` terminal (connecting the error amp to the main power output section, not shown).

Because real systems are messy, it matters what the impedances are on relevant nodes; poles and zeroes arise from multiple causes (both structure and choice of component values); and they interact in odd and often unpredictable ways.  (Note that drawing a Bode plot of the above error amp, doesn't tell you much about what actual RC values you need within it; and note that cutting the loop at the X, or even at the R+C, doesn't tell you much about overall stability or transient response.)

So, my practice tends to be:

**Third,** tuning the loop.  Put in default likely-safe values, and adjust them until stability and bandwidth are optimized.

Component values can be changed fairly roughly, say in steps of 2x up or down; RC time constants have quite gentle frequency dependence, and it's rare that some unexpected pole or zero conspires to cause instability for initial or too-slow values starting out.  The exact landscape, from initial to final values, in terms of some performance metric say (cutoff frequency, output impedance, ringing), need not be obvious or straightforward; but it's usually not terribly lumpy or unstable, and so by adjusting values back and forth, something close to the global minima can be found.

So, to explain what I meant at the start of this section: while I've denied myself the value of the loop-breaking method, that value isn't really all that great in general, because the real world is often messier than it assumes; or, sure we can design circuits to obey such assumptions (like your case, the loop-opening point is pretty clear and well defined, and the impedances on either side of the point aren't crazy), but if we need to save component count or cost, a more compact network may be necessary anyway (like the classic TL431 circuit above), and then we're kind of back to square one.

Likewise, I've transcended it, in that, given that real systems are often more complex anyway, and given I've developed a strong enough understanding to work from, say, output transient response, rather than the loop Bode plot, it doesn't really bother me to not adopt such methods.

**Further consideration** is likewise irrelevant, because of the overarching nature of work -- why we're doing this in the first place, I mean.  I don't tune control loops every day of my working life, and I have a method that works well enough to satisfy my curiosity about the system's behavior (whatever about it I haven't modeled, or that differs in practice), while achieving adequate final results.

Perhaps if it were the core responsibility of my work, to tune control loops -- I would invest in a DSA or VNA, coupling networks, adopt a process closer to the theoretical ideal; insist that designs I'm given* can easily be broken open in this way; and as a result, arrive at calculated, tested component values/parameters much more quickly (minutes rather than hours, say).

*Evidently I wouldn't be designing most of them myself, as this paragraph already assumes I'm spending most of my time tuning them.

Equally well, there will be those stuck in their ways, who did adopt this method as their primary approach to such problems.  That's fine too; ultimately, as long as the end result (overall system performance) is satisfactory, that's what matters.

A fraction of which, will even ramble on in agonizing detail, how to do it, strictly adhering to such-and-such formalisms, blessed with incense [solder rosin] and incantations...  Well, I sarcast, of course, but to be just as far, look at who's doing the rambling today...

Anyway, such formalities, I have no interest in.  Pick a method that gets you where you need to go, and understand it.  It doesn't have to be formal, it doesn't need specialized test equipment*, but it does need to develop understanding of the system under test, and tuning it to a desirable closed-loop state.

*Not that a DSA/VNA is particularly special, and they are quite useful in general.  But they are more special than the staples: say a scope and sig gen.  And you'll usually be doing this testing with a signal coupling transformer, which is fairly specialized to this task, to be fair.

Comment: W.r.t. the ``According to the person in charge`` from the question, I took that as the person who gave Virgil_Tibbs the assignment, rather than a comment about this stackexchange site.

Comment: That's a good point; maybe this is still homework after all. Context is important!

Comment: Well, the "person in charge" gave me the task to build the voltage regulator circuit, I just got stuck on the minutia of determining the open loop gain and then got chewed out for not using the second method I presented above.

Comment: "This site is most definitely not a substitute for an accredited university curriculum; so, if you for some reason need to be trained in the exact formalism used by academia... you'd be best off asking academia." - I wouldn't be asking questions like this on this forum if my need to know was being satisfied by my own local flavor of academia :)

Comment: Ahhh, yes... it is difficult to account for the variation between academia, unfortunately.